# Can I make a latticed cream pie (no-bake filling)?

Tags: baking, pie

I want to experiment with a cream pie with a nonbaked filling (containing whipped cream, thickened with gelatine - basically a flavored diplomat cream). But for aesthetical reasons, as well as a better crust-to-filling ratio, I want to try it with a lattice. But I don't have much experience with double-crust pies, so I am not sure how to make it.

My first idea is to blindbake the double crust, then remove the "weights" and get the filling somehow into the pie. I normally use white beans as weights. But I am not sure how I can get them out without breaking the lattice, as they are quite heavy. Also, I normally line the crust with alu foil when blindbaking. How can I get the alu foil out, and how can I prevent the beans from sticking to the lattice? I don't think there will be problems with the filling, I think a piping bag can get it in while still semi-liquid.

The second idea is to bake the lattice separately. I would weave it, put it on something of the right size (I have a glass cake pan bottom, could use it without attaching the pan wall) and bake. Blindbake the low crust, then fill the pie, then cover with the lattice. The question is, how to attach it to the pie?

Has anybody tried this before? I think that the second idea is more feasible than the first, any comments? Or are there other tricks I haven't thought of? Any reason why this will or won't work?

Answer (score 4):

The second option is your way to go. Fashion your lattice on a cookie sheet lined with parchment or Silpat that is twice the size that the lattice will be. Use dabs of pancake syrup, maple syrup, fruit syrup or egg white to seal the strips where necessary. To the side, lay out a piece of paper or cardboard and invert your pie plate on it. Draw the outline of your pie plate and cut the paper on that line. Use it as a lightweight template to trim your lattice to size. Egg wash your lattice and bake it until it reaches the color you want it to be. Let it cool so it hardens up, and then fold the excess of the parchment or Silpat mat over the lattice so you can lift it without breaking it. Slide the lattice off the parchment and onto your pie, color side up, and affix with syrup or egg white.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the second idea is much more feasible, as you need access to the base for weighing-down purposes.

You will need to be careful to make sure the diameter of the lattice matches the base very well. I would attach the lattice with some dabs of caramelised sugar, as it's sweet and should dry like glue.

Comment: Would dabs of the cream be fit as glue?

Comment: No, I don't think so - it wouldn't be sticky.